# Trying to prepend text depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace and then prepend text on an element and can not seem to get it to work.  I had the replace working and then it seemed to stop when I tried to prepend the text.

HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">
<p>Have Questions? Call us at: <b>1.555.55.5555</b></p>
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Login</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function replacePhone() {
if ($(window).width() < 786) {
    console.log($("#topbar p").text());
    var text = $("#topbar p").text().replace('Have Questions?', '');
    $("#topbar p").text(text)
}
if ($(window).width() > 786) {
    console.log($("#topbar p").text());
    var text = $("#topbar p").prepend.('Have Questions?');
    $("#topbar p").text(text)
}
}
$(window).resize(function () {
replacePhone();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
replacePhone();
});
```

Here is a fiddle if this is easier for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/LxQQe/

Comment: Could this be used with media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS media queries:

```css
@media (min-width: 786px) {
  #topbar p:before {
    content: "Have Questions? ";
  }
}
```

Comment: @KevinB Yes that worked the way that I needed.  Thanks for the help and the fiddle!